# Prestashop 1.6 : Display a line TotalProductsTaxes in order-detail.tpl

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to display a Total Taxes line in the Order-Detail.tpl

I added that line of code but I don't know what to write to get `TotalProductsTaxes` instead of `TotalProductsWithoutTaxes`.

I tried several things but they all broke the page.

```
<tr class="item">
    <td colspan="{if $return_allowed}2{else}1{/if}">
        <strong>{l s='TVA :'}</strong>
    </td>
    <td colspan="{if $order->hasProductReturned()}5{else}4{/if}">
        <span class="price">{displayWtPriceWithCurrency price=$order->getTotalProductsWithoutTaxes() currency=$currency}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the the price with tax and the price without tax you can calculate the tax amount and store the value in variable:

```
{assign var='totalTax' value=$total_products_wt - $total_products}

{displayWtPriceWithCurrency price=$totalTax currency=$currency}</span>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I had to adapt the code to Prestashop's structure

Comment: {assign var='totalTax' value=$order->getTotalProductsWithTaxes() - $order->getTotalProductsWithoutTaxes()}

{displayWtPriceWithCurrency price=$totalTax currency=$currency}